# How to exclude classes with @Configuration in @SpringBootApplication testing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

I am using a dependent module called spring-cloud-aws. It has a @Configuration class as org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration
In my SpringBoot JUnit test case the SqsConfiguration class is getting detected and Beans are getting initialized. I want to exclude this Configuration in class in my JUNit test case. How to achieve this ?

I tried using @ComponentScan it didn't work.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SQLTestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BusinessManagerTest {

}

@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"package1","package1"},
excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = SqsConfiguration.class)})
@Profile("test")
class SQLTestConfig {   

    @Bean
    public SomeBean beans() {

        return new SomeBean();
    }



}
```

Loading this configuration class requires aws credentials to be available. I don't want to inject credentials for running a simple Bean test case.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is expired

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to exclude specific auto-configuration during testing:

- exclude via properties in your `application-test.properties`

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration
```

- exclude via `@TestPropertySource`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SQLTestConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties ="spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration")
```

- exclude via `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, e.g.:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SQLTestConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=SqsConfiguration.class)
```

Choose one that suites you better ;)

Comment: I actually tried all of these. I got an error "The following class(SqsConfiguration) is not an Auto configuration class to exclude". Not sure what to do.

Comment: @user91604 Yes indeed. I just blindly assumed `SqsConfiguration` is auto-configuration (facepalm). I checked SqsConfiguration on github - it turns out 2 configs are used to enable SQS - `SqsClientConfiguration` and `SqsConfiguration`. Let's try to exclude them both in `excludeFilters` ?

Comment: @user91604 Also if suggestion with exclusion doesn't work, let's try approach from [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/225#issuecomment-303674594). Seems like it's common problem and guys figured out to mock SQS for tests.

Answer (score 0):

So to disable the auto-loading of all Beans for a Test, the test class can explicitly mention the dependencies required. This can be done using `ContextConfiguration` annotation. eg,

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EmployeeService.class})
public class EmployeeLeavesTest { 

   @Autowired
   private EmployeeService employeeService;

}
```

In this eg, only EmployeeService class will be available and other beans will not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but verified with SpringBoot 3.1.4 and Java 21:

- create an empty mock of the offending bean, this will override the autoconfiguration of the original bean from your @Configuration class

Take note, I don't encourage this. But I'm also guilty of making it work this way in one of my testclasses.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test") // non-necessary annotation
class ApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private YourCustomBean yourCustomBean;

    @Test
    void test_something_that_does_not_use_your_custom_bean() {
        // test your code here...
    }

}
```